# Firefox submits number fields as decimals

Tags: html

Firefox seems to submit input fields of type number as decimals independant of its visible value (e.g.: visible value: 1, real value/posted data: 1.0).
My backend cannot handle it as it expects an integer.
But I still want to use the number type as it handles the keyboard layout on mobile devices.

I already tried to set the step attribute to 1 (which is default anyway).

Comment: What programming language are you using in the backend?

Comment: The easiest way to solve this would be to change the backend code.

Comment: You could also just have a second hidden input that adds an integer to the  hidden input onchange of the number input.

Comment: That is my answer actually @Darren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you are stuck with this way of formatting number fields if you want to keep using that type of control.

What you can do is create a hidden `input` that is updated when the number input field changes. You can format the value you put in there the way you like to.

So in short, the best thing is to get your backend straight, but that might be out of your hands. Else you can use the workaround provided.

Answer (score 1):

Well actually it’s not a bug; the form field is behaving as defined by the [W3C](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/input.number.html).

Numeric input fields can take additional attributes **“min”** and **“step”**, which constrain the range of values allowed in your input.

This is because the default step is 1. So far, so obvious.

However, the step attribute also determines which values are valid, so a step of 1 means you can enter 1, 2, 3 etc. and a step of 2 means you can enter 2, 4, 6 etc, and when you click the up/down buttons the number will increase/decrease by 2 each time, but entering 3 or 5 in the box will cause a validation error. You can also use a decimal value: for example, a step of 0.3 will allow values such as 0.3, 0.6, 0.9 etc, but not 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

I was completely wrong. I filled the input from my backend and it was a double value. When using the type integer it only submits "1".